# input[type=text] submit different value than displayed

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am developing an app using Rails and jQuery. I would like to submit an id integer value via an input form but still display a friendly text value to the user while he is filling out the form. The text input field is using jQuery autocomplete so once the user chooses an entry, an integer value will be put into the input field. Is there any way to display a different value from what is actually submitted?

Comment: What about moving the part that figures out what is the number from the text to rails?

Comment: I could do that but I really want to keep my controller as clean as possible. Also, I have multiple cases of this (large form) so I'd have to add quite a bit of custom code in the controller. I'm wondering if there's some pre-built plugin or way to do this. If not I guess I'll end up putting it into the controller.

Comment: you used to be able to do things like this in action actionscript in datagrids)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the combobox functionality for the jQuery UI Autocomplete:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

The value attribute of the options are what get sent along with the form, not the display text.

Comment: Oh, I totally overlooked the combobox example! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without adding a dropdown box, and just have that textbox?

Comment: @lynnyi and where would you show the options of autocompletion?

Comment: @OhCaN I see. I guess I don't understand Combobox all that well. So in this example, it seems as if the display text and the input values are statically laid out, i.e. "Fortran" maps to value=Fortran. So in the case where I grab a list of names in JSON format from sql, I want to have the value "LastName, FirstName" while displaying "FirstName LastName" -- will this be possible?  I guess in general, I don't understand why there's a new widget, Combobox. Why isn't there just an extension to Autocomplete?

Comment: @lynnyi Yes, the display doesn't have to equal the value. It is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can also keep a hidden input field, and use a "change" event to keep the hidden input field updated every time the user changes the original field.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you want to do.
I have done the same thing for a drop down.
Never tried for a text box though!:(
What I did was that the dropdown displayed name of entries in database and when user submits the form,the ID in the database is passed.
I hope thats precisely what you want.
I am putting the code for the same below.
I know this is not what you are looking for but it may give you a hint !

In the view:

> <%= f.select :facilitator_group_id, FacilitatorGroup.all.map { |fg|
>   [fg.name, fg.id] } %>

FacilitatotGroup is my model name.

Cheers !

Hi.I also feel that the reason we use textfield is for user to enter data which they wanna store in DB.
For your reason, why cant you use a dropdown ?

Comment: Your code only works for a dropdown. Options tags have both a text and value property, text boxes don't. I can't use a dropdown because I am using the jQuery autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('myform').submit(function() { /* your thing here */ });
```

And your thing will run when the user submits.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. But that would I mean I still need to do a lot of manual work by keeping track and replacing all of the values I want to modify. In that case I could put it into the controller which would be a much cleaner solution. Or am I overlooking something?